# Generating Completions file for exo in fish

Tags: fish, completion, exo

I'm new to deref/exo and I'm trying to make my development environment more friendly. I use fish, and a coworker suggested running `exo completion install` which should infer that I'm using Fish and correctly install the completion file to fish wherever it goes.

Instead I'm getting this "cannot infer completion installation path" error:

```
> exo completion install
  inferred shell: fish
  Error: cannot infer completion installation path
  cannot infer completion installation path
```

Comment: Thanks @tosh for tagging it Exo, and NotTheDr01ds, I am not sure that exoscale is the same as deref/exo, here: https://github.com/deref/exo
which I use it to control and serve/host processes locally, so I was looking for info here (I run it on a Mac).

Comment: My apologies, I thought this was the `exo` command for Exoscale.  It *isn't*.  Definitely a "developer tool", then, so I'm going to retract my close vote (I try to be lenient if it comes anywhere near "development" ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

I have had difficulty finding solutions to exo issues as  What eventually worked for me as there is apparently both a K-Pop boy band and some challenge in Destiny 2 that keep stealing my googles. Here's a breadcrumb for the next generation that follows:

I eventually read that fish tries to help programs (like brew, which already had a completion file in there when I looked) install their completions scripts by [providing this command](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/completions.html):
`pkg-config --variable completionsdir fish`
That resolved to /usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/ on my system. So, although exo was unable to automatically generate the file, I was able to dump it into there like so:
`exo completion generate fish > /usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/exo.fish`

More generally, `exo completion generate fish > (pkg-config --variable completionsdir fish)/exo.fish`

That alone seemed to do the trick for me, but you may also need to source that exo.fish file

`. /usr/local/share/fish/vendor_completions.d/exo.fish`

Update: The [MR](https://github.com/deref/exo/pull/528) to fix this issue has been merged, hopefully nobody needs this answer and the issue is moot.